# API Gateway and Swagger UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger-ui, aws-api-gateway, swagger-editor

I currently have an API with multiple resources within our API Gateway, I'm working on a a Swagger UI page for the same.

A lot of the swagger ui definition I have written myself, although I know there is export functionality - it doesn't seem 100% ready yet.

When using the `Try it out` button from swagger, if I get back a 200, this is handled perfectly and the result shows as expected. I am trying to get the error codes to display and this is where I am stuck.

In API Gateway I have create a 401 in my `Method response`, including some allowed headers, this is being used in my `Integration Response` for `HTTP status regex` of `Unauthorized.*` - the content of this is just being passed through.

My swagger UI definition response looks like this (for the 401 in particular):

```
"401": {
"description": "Unauthorized",
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
            "type": "string"
                   }
        }
},
```

This is just expecting a string response. My `produces' has everything needed, just in case;

```
"produces": ["application/json",
            "text/json",
            "application/xml",
            "text/xml"],
```

The result through the inspector is correct - 
[image]

However my swagger still produces this:

[image]

I have tried a multitude of things, including assigning an object to the response type, changing my regex expression to 4\d{2} to catch any 400 error, updated the definition produces - all with no luck.

Let me know if there is any other information needed to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a custom authorizer or Cognito authorizer and this is what is producing the 401?

Unfortunately there is a known limitation where error methods, such as 401 or 403 from an authorizer, will not contain configured header mappings.

Comment: What about other errors or responses (I.e. 500 / 429 etc.) Other than 200, no other response are produced (I only know they happening by inspecting the page network)

Comment: Errors generated *by* API Gateway (e.g. 500 or 429) will exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: So basically you saying that, unless 200 - I won't get any other responses back with this scenario?

Comment: No, if your backend generates a non-200, then things work as expected. This problem occurs if the non-200 is generated *by* API Gateway (permission denied, internal error, throttling, etc).

Comment: Hi Bob, just checking that this is still a limitation and no fix has yet been implemented?

Comment: @Hexie, unfortunately, yes, this is still a limitation. We are working on a solution to address this, but I can't commit to a timeline when it would be available.

Comment: For anyone that runs into this issue - see the following threads for additional information: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3403 and https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=728839

Comment: Finally the limitation is fixed.